# "failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = refusing to create a tag with a digest reference" When "docker compose up"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

When I command "docker compose up" after finishing docker compose build, the follow error occured.

```
> exporting to image:
------
failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = refusing to create a tag with a digest reference
```

I looked at the reason, but I don't understand why this error occurs.

Comment: You need to add more logs and the yml file for us to help you, most likely this is due to an error in your yml file, for example the repo you refer to is not created. It can somtimes also happen if multiple env is building the same image.

Answer (score 0):

I found that removing the line

```
build:
```

from the container's block in the docker compose file, resolved the issue for me.